# What is the best way to count "find" results?

Tags: bash, find

My current solution would be `find <expr> -exec printf '.' \; | wc -c`, but this takes far too long when there are more than 10000 results. Is there no faster/better way to do this?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Try this instead (require `find`'s `-printf` support):

```
find <expr> -type f -printf '.' | wc -c
```

It will be more reliable and faster than counting the lines.

Note that I use the `find`'s `printf`, not an external command.

---

Let's bench a bit :

```
$ ls -1
a
e
l
ll.sh
r
t
y
z
```

My snippet benchmark :

```
$ time find -type f -printf '.' | wc -c
8

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.007s
```

With full lines :

```
$ time find -type f | wc -l
8

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.000s
```

So my solution is faster =) (the important part is the `real` line)

Comment: @RandyHoward One dot for each file found, is equivalent to one line for each file found.

Comment: Not equivalent, it's more reliable =)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFoukarakis, I didn't look closely enough.  Probably because that usage doesn't work here, -printf isn't a valid option for find on OS X that I'm using just now.  Is that a gnu extension?  This does work though: find <expr> -type f -exec printf '.' \l; | wc -l

Comment: It's not more reliable if the -printf flag to find isn't supported on your platform.  ;-)

Comment: Added note about this in my post

Comment: Note that you can shave off a few more nanoseconds by not quoting the dot in `-printf '.'`

Comment: @Jens - especially when you take into account the time taken to type that

Comment: With such a small benchmark, the timings are probably dominated by other factors than the thing you want to measure.  An experiment with a big tree would be more useful.  But this gets my vote for actually doing what the OP asked for.

Comment: Your solution is nor more reliable nor quicker. Here is more reliable bench : '.' count method 10407 files - real 0m0.121s VS line count method 10407 files -  real 0m0.052s

Comment: @AdrienHorgnies, filenames can have newlines in them. Counting dots is *definitely* more reliable.

Comment: Anyone reading these comments should know that all of the bickering over the speed of commands is largely a waste of time. Spend your time writing readable code that  is closest to O(1) to O(n) as possible and not bean count the commands themselves. I've had coworkers fight about such nonsense while ironically writing code that *needlessly* ran in exponential time.

Comment: Just a small note. I'm using this method in a subshell to return a count or -1 if the `find` command encounters errors. Since `wc -c` counts ALL characters, anyone thinking of storing the dots in a variable and then later `echo`ing them into `wc` should make sure to use `echo -n` to prevent a newline from being echoed, as that newline will be counted as well. E.g.:

```numFiles=$(dots=`find ~/Downloads -type f -printf '.'` && echo -n $dots | wc -c || echo "-1")```

Note the `-n` argument. In other words, `echo -n | wc -c` is 0 while `echo | wc -c` is 1, because `\n` is also a character.

Answer (score 183):

Why not

```
find <expr> | wc -l
```

as a simple portable solution? Your original solution is *spawning a new process* `printf` for every individual file found, and that's very expensive (as you've just found).

Note that this will overcount if you have filenames with newlines embedded, but if you have that then I suspect your problems run a little deeper.

Comment: -1 : will breaks on file with newlines, and it's slower than counting bytes =)

Comment: I don;t think that warrants a downvote given that the filename/newline limitation is pretty rare *and* noted above. Slower ? Perhaps. Given you're querying a filesystem I suspect the speed difference is small. Across my 10,000 files I measure 3ms difference

Comment: The performance difference between 'find <expr> |wc -l' and 'find <expr> -printf . |wc -c' are extremely small. Caching (i.e. if you run the same find twice over the same tree) is much more important.
IMHO the solution with "wc -l" is a lot more intuitive.

Answer (score 10):

POSIX compliant and newline-proof:

```
find /path -exec printf %c {} + | wc -c
```

And, from my tests in `/`, not even two times slower than the other solutions, which are either not newline-proof or not portable.

Note the `+` instead of `\;`. That is crucial for performance, as `\;` spawns one `printf` command per file name, whereas `+` gives as much file names as it can to a single `printf` command. (And in the possible case where there are too many arguments, Find intelligently spawns new Printfs on demand to cope with it, so it would be as if

```
{ 
  printf %c very long argument list1
  printf %c very long argument list2
  printf %c very long argument list3 
} | wc -c
```

were called.)

Answer (score 8):

This is my `countfiles` function in my `~/.bashrc` (it's reasonably fast, should work for Linux & FreeBSD `find`, and does not get fooled by file paths containing newline characters; the final `wc` just counts NUL bytes):

```
countfiles () 
{ 
   command find "${1:-.}" -type f -name "${2:-*}" -print0 | 
       command tr -dc '\0' | command wc -c;
return 0
}

countfiles

countfiles ~ '*.txt'
```

Answer (score 8):

This solution is certainly slower than some of the other `find -> wc` solutions here, but if you were inclined to do something else with the file names in addition to counting them, you could `read` from the `find` output.

```
n=0
while read -r -d ''; do
    ((n++)) # count
    # maybe perform another act on file
done < <(find <expr> -print0)
echo $n
```

It is just a modification of [a solution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) found in BashGuide that properly handles files with nonstandard names by making the `find` output delimiter a NUL byte using `print0`, and reading from it using `''` (NUL byte) as the loop delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something where I wouldn't take all output from find as some other commands run also print stuff.

Without need for temporary files this is only possible with a big caveat: You might get (far) more than one line of output as it will execute the output command once for every 800~1600 files.

```sh
find . -print -exec sh -c 'printf %c "$@" | wc -c' '' '{}' + # just print the numbers
find . -print -exec sh -c 'echo "Processed `printf %c "$@" | wc -c` items."' '' '{}' +
```

Generates this result:

```
Processed 1622 items.
Processed 1578 items.
Processed 1587 items.
```

An alternative is to use a temporary file:

```sh
find . -print -fprintf tmp.file .
wc -c <tmp.file # using the file as argument instead causes the file name to be printed after the count

echo "Processed `wc -c <tmp.file` items." # sh variant
echo "Processed $(wc -c <tmp.file) items." # bash variant
```

The `-print` in every of the find commands will not influence the count at all.