# Bash script that writes subdirectories who has more than 5 files

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

while I was trying to practice my linux skills, but I could not solve this question.

> So its basically saying  "Write a bash script that takes  a name of
>   directory as a command argument and printf the name of subdirectories
>   that has more than 5 files in it."

I thought we will use the `find` command but ı still could not figure it out. My code is:

```
find directory -type d -mindepth5
```

but it's not working.

Comment: find doesn't have that capability you'll have to find another way to count the number of files. they want you to write it in bash. perhaps use globs.

Comment: That's not what the `-mindepth` switch is for. It specifies that only results in subdirectories 5 levels deep are included. Is that your full script?

Comment: Something ugly like this should work fairly efficiently: `find directory -type d -exec bash -c 'nb=$(find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "x\n" | head -6 | wc -l); ((nb>5))' {} \; -print`. Not too sure that's the kind of answer you're expecting, though.

Comment: No, I dont even have a idea now how should it be because I dont know how am i gonna make the structure

Comment: Hello gniourf, ur code is working absolutely fine can u explain it pls?  thanks so much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15663607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` twice:

First you can use `find` and `wc` to count the number of *files* in a given directory:

```
nb=$(find directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "x\n" | wc -l)
```

This just asks `find` to output an `x` on a line for each *file* in the directory `directory`, proceeding non-recursively, then `wc -l` counts the number of lines, so, really, `nb` is the number of files in `directory`.

If you want to know whether a directory contains more than 5 files, it's a good idea to stop `find` as soon as 6 files are found:

```
nb=$(find directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "x\n" | head -6 | wc -l)
```

Here `nb` has an upper threshold of `6`.

Now if for each subdirectory of a directory `directory` you want to output the number of files (threshold at 6), you can do this:

```
find directory -type d -exec bash -c 'nb=$(find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "x\n" | head -6 | wc -l); echo "$nb"' {} \;
```

where the `$0` that appears is the `0`-th argument, namely `{}` that `find` will replaced by the subdirectory of `directory`.

Finally, you only want to display the subdirectory name if the number of files is more than 5:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'nb=$(find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "x\n" | head -6 | wc -l); ((nb>5))' {} \; -print
```

The final test `((nb>5))` returns success or failure whether `nb` is greater than 5 or not, and in case of success, `find` will `-print` the subdirectory name.

Comment: Am I right when I say this runs a new process of `$(find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "x\n" | head -6 | wc -l); ((nb>5))'` for every single file listed and will therefore be really slow for large amounts of files (e.g. when trying on `/`)? Edit: tested your solution on over 8000 files with time over 18 seconds while my answer does the same in less then a second. However original question was not about speed.

Comment: @JanLegner you're right, this spawns an insane number of processes for each subdirectory, and will be slow on `/`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
find directory/ -type f | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | awk '{if($1>5) print($2)}'
```

Using `mindpeth` is useless here since it only lists directories at at least depth 5. You say you need subdirectories with more then 5 files in it.

`find directory -type f` prints all files in subdirectories
`sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/g'` removes names of files leaving only list of subdirecotries without filenames
`sort` sorts that list so we can use `uniq`
`uniq -c` merges duplicate lines and writes how many times it occured
`sort -n` sorts it by number of occurences (so you end up with a list:(how many times, subdirectory))
`awk '{if($1>5) print($2)}'` prints only those with first comlun 1 > 5 (and it only prints the second column)
So you end up with a list of subdirectories with at least 5 files inside.

EDIT:
A fix for paths with spaces was proposed:
Instead of `awk '{if($1>5) print($2)}'` there should be `awk '{if($1>5){ $1=""; print(substr($0,2)) }}'` which sets first part of line to `""` and then prints whole line without a leading space (which was delimiter). So put together we get this:

```
find directory/ -type f | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | awk '{if($1>5){ $1=""; print(substr($0,2)) }}'
```

Comment: You should fix your answer so that is works with directory names containing spaces (though it's unfixable for directory names containing newlines).