# Using find command to find file modification times

Tags: linux, unix, find

I'm trying to answer this question:

use the find command to determine cumulatively how many files with names ending in .h within /usr/include and its sub-directories have been modified within the last 400 days. You may use wc in your solution.

To answer this question, copy and paste the exact command you used to find the answer.

Hint: Your answer should fit in the provided space for an answer.

Hint: Use man find to research find commands based on file modification times.

So far I am using:

```
find usr/include -name '*.h' -mtime -399 | wc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this

```
find /usr/include -type f -mtime -400 -name "*.h"
```

- `-type f` check just files
- `-mtime -400` make time lower than 400 days
- `-name "*.h"` name ending with `h`.

Then it is a matter of counting occurrences.

In case some names contain new lines, you may want to use `-printf '.' | wc -c`, as described in [bash - What is the best way to count find-results?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15663760/1983854).

Comment: In Linux, execute the following command to download the "First Monday" article:

wget -O first_monday.html http://www.uic.edu/htbin/cgiwrap/bin/ojs/index.php/fm/article/view/3156/2747

Use sed and regular expressions to edit first_monday.html as follows:
1.Remove empty/blank paragraphs, if any. (HTML paragraph starting tag is <p> and ending tag is </p>)

<p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>

A paragraph is empty if there is nothing or has only spaces or tabs in between <p> and </p>

Comment: 2.Remove all images (In HTML, images are defined with the <img> tag. Example: <img src="html5.gif" alt="The official HTML5 Icon">   
3.The resulting file should still be a valid HTML file, displayable in a standard web browser. 

For your answer, copy/paste the commands you used to answer this question.  For example, if you used a command similar to sed -iback -e 's|<p>[[:space:]]*</p>||g' first_monday.html  then you would paste that command as well as any others you used in the answer for this field.
I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: Could you help with this?

Comment: @sa044512 no, this should be a new question.

Comment: It won't let me ask another question.

Comment: @sa044512 then you should do some research yourself and try asking again after a while. I am pretty sure there are similar question here that can be useful for a start.