# Count number of subdirectories ignoring parent directories

Tags: linux, bash, directory, directory-structure, subdirectory

I would like to count number of subdirectories in depth 2, but ignore the parent directories of depth 1 in the bash script.

**Example:**

```
root_dir ---|--ignore_dir ---|--count_dir
            |                |--count_dir ---|--ignore_dir
            |                                |--ignore_dir
            |--ignore_dir ---|--count_dir
                             |--count_dir
                             |--count_dir
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
find /path/to/root_dir -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d | wc -l
```

Here we explicitely limit the depth of `find` to 2 (no more, no less) and list all directories. `wc -l` counts the number of lines from the output of the `find` command.

**Note:**

If your folders names contain newlines, specific characters or unusual encoding, using `wc -l` will yield incorrect results.

Taking inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663607/bash-what-is-the-best-way-to-count-find-results), you can instead print a character for each folder found, and count the resulting number of characters.

You could use the following snippet :

```
find /path/to/root_dir -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -printf '.' | wc -c
```

Comment: While this answers the question, one should be careful when names have newline characters in it. ([Never parse the output of `ls` or `find`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs))

Comment: @kvantour I've edited my answer to address the "special characters in output" edge case

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is through globbing

```
ls /path/to/root_dir/*/*/ -d | wc -l
```

I find this type of solution easier to remember, but it's not as easily 'scalable' (e.g. to many deapth levels) as the `find`-one

Comment: While this answers the question, one should be careful when names have newline characters in it. ([Never parse the output of `ls` or `find`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs))