# Using find with printf and or

Tags: shell, find

I'm confused about using `find` and combining `-printf` with `-o`. Say I have some files in a directory like

```
$ ls
a1  b1
```

and I want to use `find` with two filters. Starting with AND:

```
find . -iname "a*" -iname "*1"
./a1
```

and using `-printf` [for counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663607/bash-what-is-the-best-way-to-count-find-results):

```
find . -iname "a*" -iname "*1" -printf '.'
.
```

Seems fine. Now trying the same thing with an `-o` to get the OR of the two filters:

```
$ find . -iname "a*" -o -iname "*1"
./b1
./a1
$ find . -iname "a*" -o -iname "*1" -printf '.'
.
```

Why don't I get `..`? Changing the order of arguments doesn't help:

```
$ find . -printf '.' -iname "a*" -o -iname "*1" 
...
```

EDIT:

```
$ find . -type f \( -iname "a*" -o -iname "*1" \)
..
```

gives the expected behavior, see the accepted answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the section `OPERATORS` of the `find` man page:

> OPERATORS
>
> Listed in order of decreasing precedence:
>
> ```
> ( expr )
> ```
>
> Force precedence.  Since parentheses are special to the shell, you will normally need to quote them.  Many of the examples in this manual page use backslashes for this purpose: `'\(...\)'` instead of `'(...)'`.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> expr1 expr2
> ```
>
> Two expressions in a row are taken to be joined with an implied "and"; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is false.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> expr1 -o expr2
> ```
>
> Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.

And then, emphasis mine:

> Please  note  that `-a` when specified implicitly (for example by two tests appearing without an explicit operator between them) or explicitly has higher precedence than `-o`.  **This means that `find . -name afile -o -name bfile -print` will never print afile.**