# Bash: Check if a directory contains only files with a specific suffix

Tags: bash, directory, file-exists

I am trying to write a script that will check if a directory contains only
a specific kind of file (and/or folder) and will return 1 for false, 0 for true.

IE: I want to check if `/my/dir/` contains only `*.gz` files and nothing else.

This is what i have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended:

```
# Basic vars
readonly       THIS_JOB=${0##*/}
readonly       ARGS_NBR=1


declare        dir_in=$1


dir_in=$1"/*.gz"
#echo $dir_in

files=$(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; echo ! $dir_in)
echo $files

if (( ${#files} ))
then
    echo "Success: Directory contains files."
    exit 0
else
    echo "Failure: Directory is empty (or does not exist or is a file)"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check if /my/dir/ contains only *.gz files and nothing else.

Use `find` instead of globulation. It's really easier to use `find` and to parse find output. Globulation are simple for simple scripts, but once you want to parse "all files in a directory" and do some filtration and such, it's way easier (and safer) to use `find`:

```
find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \! -name '*.gz' -o \! -type f | wc -l | xargs test 0 -eq
```

This finds all "things" that are not named `*.gz` inside the directory or are not files (so `mkdir a.gz` is accounted for), counts them, and then tests if they're count is equal to 0. If the count is equal to 0, `xargs test 0 -eq` will return 0, if not, it will return status between `1 - 125`. You can handle the nonzero return status with a simple `|| return 1` if you wish.

You can remove `xargs` with a simple bash substitution and use the method from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663607/bash-what-is-the-best-way-to-count-find-results) for a little speedup and get `test` return value, which is `0` or `1`:

```
[ 0 -eq "$(find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \! -name '*.gz' -o \! -type f -print '.' | wc -c)" ]
```

Remember that the exit status of a script is the exit status of the last command executed. So you don't need anything else in your script if you wish, only a shebang and this oneliner will suffice.

Comment: not sure you can guarantee xargs will return 123 (freebsd returns 1) but certainly should be a value between 1..125

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bash, there is another setting you can use: `GLOBIGNORE`

```
#!/bin/bash

containsonly(){
    dir="$1"
    glob="$2"

    if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
        echo 1>&2 "Failure: directory does not exist"
        return 2
    fi

    local res=$(
        cd "$dir"
        GLOBIGNORE=$glob"
        shopt -s nullglob dotglob
        echo *
    )
    if [ ${#res} = 0 ]; then
        echo 1>&2 "Success: directory contains no extra files"
        return 0
    else
        echo 1>&2 "Failure: directory contains extra files"
        return 1
    fi
}

# ...

containsonly myfolder '*.gz'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Bash's `extglob`, `!(*.gz)` and `grep`:

```
$ if grep -qs . path/!(*.gz) ; then echo yes ; else echo nope ; fi
```

`man grep`:

```
-q, --quiet, --silent
       Quiet;  do  not  write  anything  to  standard   output.    Exit
       immediately  with  zero status if any match is found, even if an
       error was detected.  Also see the -s or --no-messages option.

-s, --no-messages
       Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.
```

Answer (score 1):

Some have suggested to count all files which do not match the globbing pattern `*.gz`. This might be quite inefficient depending on the the number of files. For you job it is sufficient to find just one file, which does not match your globbing pattern. Use the `-quite` action of `find` to exit after the first match:

```
if [ -z "$(find /usr/share/man/man1/* -not -name '*.gz' -print -quit)" ]
then echo only gz
fi
```

Comment: `-not` and `-quit` are not POSIX compliant, I think. `-not` can simply be replaced by `!` but `-quit` doesn't exist in `busybox` for example. In that case, since we have bash, I suppose it could be replaced with something like `-exec bash -c 'kill -PIPE $PPID' \;` (or just `find ... | head -n 1`)

Comment: @jhnc someone who uses one GNU tool, the Bash, probably uses also the other GNU tools and does not bother about POSIX compliance.

Comment: I'm using bash on freebsd but many of the utilities aren't GNU