# Is it possible to list files that match a pattern with ls?

Tags: bash, shell, file, sh, ls

I want to list files of a directory with `ls` that match a pattern without using `grep`. Is it possible?

The point is to retrieve all files that match this pattern `'^\Extra_text_[0-9]\{10\}.csv'`
and count how much I got.

I tried this code:

`ls | grep '^\Extra_text_[0-9]\{10\}.csv'`

`InputName=' | grep ^\Extra_text_[0-9]\{10\}.csv'`

`` fileCount=`ls $INPUT_FILE/$InputName 2>/dev/null | wc -l` ``

`echo "$fileCount`

*But it doesn't work!  :/*

Comment: `ls` shouldn't be put to programmatic use in the first place; it's built *only* to generate output for human-consumption -- see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: ...that said, as to why you can't use pipeline components (or other shell syntax) from variables, that's covered in depth in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Can you not make use of shell filename globbing ? https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

Comment: As a point of contrast, `files=( Extra_text_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv ); echo "Found ${#files[@]}"` requires no external tools *at all*.

Comment: @BrianAgnew, please don't link the ABS. More people learn bad habits from its examples than almost anywhere else. [The Wooledge wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) and [the bash-hackers' wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) are *far* better sources.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - ok. Is it out of date, or just *bad* ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew, ...both, but the *bad* is more egregious. Lots of places where they aren't careful to use good practices in examples, so trying to copy practices seen in the code included is hazardous, to the point where [a competing guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) was [written in response](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs).

Comment: @BrianAgnew, CharlesDuffy Thank you all for your responses!

Answer (score 4):

Not with `ls` only. `ls` does not know about patterns at all. It can only be used with globbing (wildcards `*` and `?` or extended globbing - see `extglob` in the Bash manual page) offered by the shell, but not with regular expressions.

An easy way is to use `find` for this job (note that the regex needs to match the whole filename):

```
find . -regex '<yourpattern>'
```

To count results, pipe to `wc`:

```
# safe for corner case: version of find w/o newline escaping and files with newlines:
find . -regex '<yourpattern>' -printf '.' | wc -c    

# fallback for non-GNU platform, corner cases not addressed:
find . -regex '<yourpattern>' | wc -l
```

Find `-regex` in the `find` manual page for more information.

Comment: If on a GNU platform, might `find ... -printf '\n' | wc -l`, removing the name itself from the output, so filenames with newlines in them can't be counted more than once even if the find version in use doesn't do any escaping in the default print action.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. Interestingly, `-printf '.' | wc -c` seems to be faster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15663760/4024473

Comment: (BTW, I wouldn't even say that `ls` understands shell patterns; it's the shell doing that expansion before `ls` starts).

Answer (score 1):

You may use file-matching metacharacters.

```
* matches any number of characters
? matches any one character
[...] matches any one of the characters between the brackets 
which can include a hyphen-separated range of letters or numbers
```

[image]
Above just an example, maybe not exactly what you are trying to do. As I can't figure out what your regex means.

```
ls -l  Extra_text_[0-9]{10}.csv | wc -l
```

You may use the command above to count how many files you get.

Reference

Negus, C. (2020) *Linux Bible, 10th Edition*. Wiley