# Filtering ls output to only display dirs/files less than certain size

Tags: bash

I am using `ls -lRa` to recursively go through my file structure.

However, when I get to large directories it takes a long time to go through them.

How do you filter this `ls -lRa` command so that if the dir it is ls on is over a certain size then it will just use `ls -la` and not waste time going recursively through the dir.

I would like to maintain the `ls -la` format.

Some basic pseudo code might be:

```
for each fileSize
do
if fileSize is greater than x
then ls -lRa on that directory 
else 
ls -la dir on that directory
fi
done
```

How would I obtain the fileSize variable in this example.

I know I can use `-ls -la | awk '{print $5}'` but how do I perform the check to see if this number is less/greater than in relation to the dir the size belongs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory: [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

You can [use `find` to count the number of files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15663607/4518341), so try something like this:

```
for dir in ./*/; do
    count="$(find "$dir" -printf '.' | wc -c)"
    if [[ $count -gt $x ]]; then
        ls -lRa "$dir"
    else
        ls -la "$dir"
    fi
done
```