# Get the count of csv files in a directory

Tags: linux, shell

I am using the below command to get the count of csv in a directory

`ll *.csv|wc -l`

But if there are no csv files it prints

```
ls: cannot access *.csv: No such file or directory
0
```

I need to store this count in a variable. If there are 10 csv files then it should store 10 and if there are no csv files it should store 0.

Comment: and what's a problem?

Comment: Understand that you are redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null` for the `ls` command. The standard stream file numbers are `0 - stdin`, `1 - stdout`, and `2 - stderr`, So by using `2 > /dev/null` you are redirecting all output on `stderr` to the *bit-bucket*.

Comment: @Abhiramvarma : Is it necessary to do it in (POSIX)-Shell? If you could do it in bash or zsh, create an array with the names of csv-files and get the number of elements. Make sure that your glob is expanded to nothing if there are no files. In Zsh, for instance, you could do it simply by `arr=(*.csv(ND)); echo $#arr`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better solution:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.csv' | wc  -l
```

...it should be noted that file names containing new lines will skew the results (the same with `ls`)

If your `find` has the `-printf` option (like GNU find), you can do this:

```
find -type f -name '*.csv' -printf '.' | wc -c
```

This both handles filenames with new lines ok, and may be faster (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663607/what-is-the-best-way-to-count-find-results) for more info).

Note that if reading from stdin (and not a file given as argument), `wc -l` or `wc -c` return numeric values, including `0`, if there is no new line for `wc -l` or no characters (empty string) for `wc -c`.